# Wiring Diagram From a Wall Switch To Two Light Fixtures

Tags: electrical

What is wiring diagram from wall switch (source) to two light fixtures ?  Isn't it fairly simple ? All blacks together,  all whites together, all grounds together with wire terminals on all connections. Turn both light fixtures on or off at same time.

Answer (score 1):

Is your [Google](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS724US724&biw=1241&bih=840&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=ewwOW8qLLKfojwT4_YBA&q=light%20switch%20wiring%20diagram%20two%20lights&oq=light%20switch%20wiring%20diagram%20two%20lights&gs_l=img.3...5706.9423.0.9527.13.12.1.0.0.0.127.964.8j3.11.0....0...1c.1.64.img..1.6.444...0j0i30k1j0i5i30k1j0i8i30k1.0.w0FIZJnHPFU) finger sore today?

[image]

Comment: Looks good go with it.